# Why does this AWS Config Rule have no results available?

Tags: aws-config

I created an AWS Config rule and lambda operating on resource type AWS::RDS::DBInstance and Trigger Type = 'Configuration changes'. CloudWatch logs verify that the function return is ...

```
{ "ResultToken": "<Redacted>",
  "Evaluations": [
        {"ComplianceResourceId": "db-<Redacted>",
         "ComplianceResourceType": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
         "ComplianceType": "COMPLIANT",
         "OrderingTimestamp": 1576676501.52}
   ]
}
```

And although the rule is successfully invoked, the AWS console claims that the compliance status of the rule is 'No results available'. Additionally, this bit of powershell script using the AWSPowershell module ...

```
Get-CFGComplianceByConfigRule -configrulename security-group-of-rds | select -expandProperty Compliance
```

... returns ...

```
INSUFFICIENT_DATA
```

**Why isn't the reported compliance status COMPLIANT?**

My first thought is that I've got the schema for the return object wrong, but based on the example functions that AWS has supplied, it looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

1. Evaluation results need to be reported via a call to config:Put_Evaluations() rather than the actual lambda return.
2. The lambda return should just be the evaluations list.

The long answer is, Here is my solution that works:

### AWS Lambda Function (language python3.8) for the Config Rule

```
'''
#####################################
##           Gherkin               ##
#####################################
Rule Name:
  security-group-of-rds
Description:
  Checks that all Oracle databases are using the correct security group and only that group.
Trigger:
  Configuration Change on AWS::RDS::DbInstance . Scope of changes == Resources.
Reports on:
  AWS::RDS::DbInstance
Parameters:
  | ----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
  | Parameter Name        | Type      | Description                                   |
  | ----------------------|-----------|---------------------------------------------- |
  | vpcSecurityGroupId    | string    | Id of the required vpc Security Group.        |
  | ----------------------|-----------|---------------------------------------------- |
  | Assume-Rule-Role      | boolean   | If true, switch to the config role.           |
  |                       |           | Defaults to false.                            |
  |-----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
  | Mode                  | Enum      | Range: Fully-Operational-DeathStar |          |
  |                       |           |        Put-Evaluations-Test |                 |
  |                       |           |        Lambda-Console-Test                    |
  |                       |           | Defaults to Fully-Operational-DeathStar .     |
  |                       |           | Meanings:                                     |
  |                       |           |   Fully-Operational-DeathStar:                |
  |                       |           |     Normal operation.                         |
  |                       |           |   Put-Evaluations-Test: Set TestMode to True, |
  |                       |           |     when invoking put_evaluations.            |
  |                       |           |     Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/APIReference/API_PutEvaluations.html
  |                       |           |   Lambda-Console-Test:                        |
  |                       |           |     Do not call put_evaluations() at all.     |                 |
  |-----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
Envars:
  | ----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
  | Envar Name            | Type      | Description                                   |
  | ----------------------|-----------|---------------------------------------------- |
  | PROXY                 | string    | http(s) proxy. Default to no proxy.           |
  |-----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
  | NO_PROXY              | comma-    | list of exemptions to proxy.                  |
  |                       | separated-| Defaults to no exemptions                     |
  |                       | list      |                                               |
  |-----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
  | TURN_OFF_SSL          | boolean   | Turns of SSL verification. Defaults to False  |
  |-----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
  | REGION                | string    | Region for config service.                    |
  |                       |           | Defaults to the lambda region                 |
  |-----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
  | CONFIG_ENDPOINT       | string    | Customised end-point for config service       |
  |                       |           | Defaults to the standard end-point.           |
  |-----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
Feature:
    In order to: to protect the data confidentiality for Oracle oracle-ee RDS databases.
             As: a Developer
         I want: To ensure that all databases have the correct security group attached.
Scenarios:
    Scenario 1:
      Given: Wrong security group
        And: The group is inactive
       Then: No conclusion.
    Scenario 2:
      Given: Wrong security group
        And: The group is active
        And: type == oracle-ee
       Then: return NON_COMPLIANT
    Scenario 3:
      Given: Right security group
        And: The group is active
        And: type == oracle-ee
       Then: return COMPLIANT
    Scenario 4:
      Given: No security group
        And: type == oracle-ee
       Then: return NON_COMPLIANT
    Scenario 5:
      Given: type != oracle-ee
       Then: return NOT_APPLICABLE
Required Role Policy Statements:
  If you are not assuming the config rule role, then the lambda role needs all these
    actions, except sts:AssumeRole.
  If you ARE assuming the config rule role, then the lambda role needs the logs and sts
    actions, and the config rule role needs the logs and config actions.
  | ----------------------|-------------|-----------------------------------------------|
  | Action                | Resource    | Condition  | Why do we need it?               |
  | ----------------------|-------------|---------------------------------------------- |
  | logs:CreateLogGroup   | *           | Always     | For logging.                     |
  | logs:CreateLogStream  |             |            |                                  |
  | logs:PutLogEvents     |             |            |                                  |
  | ----------------------|-------------|------------|----------------------------------|
  | sts:AssumeRole        | Your AWS    | if Assume-Rule-Role == True | If you want the |
  |                       | config role |            |  lambda to execute in the main   |
  |                       |             |            |  config role.                    |
  | ----------------------|-------------|------------|----------------------------------|
  | config:PutEvaluations | *           | Always     | To put the actual results.       |
  | ----------------------|-------------|------------|----------------------------------|
Inline Constants Configuration:
  | ----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------|
  | Identifier            | Type      | Description                                   |
  | ----------------------|-----------|---------------------------------------------- |
  | defaultRegion         | string    | Default region, if we can't get it from the   |
  |                       |           |   Lambda environment.                         |
  | ----------------------|-----------|---------------------------------------------- |
'''

import json
import datetime
import time
import boto3
import botocore
import os

proxy    = None
no_proxy = None
configClient  = None
defaultRegion = 'ap-southeast-2'


def setEnvar( name, value):
  if os.environ.get( name, '') != value:
    if value != '':
      os.environ[ name] = value
    else:
      del os.environ[ name]

def setProxyEnvironment():
  # Sometimes lamdba's sit in VPC's which require proxy forwards
  #  in order to access some or all internet services.
  global proxy
  global noProxy
  proxy   = os.environ.get( 'PROXY'   , None)
  noProxy = os.environ.get( 'NO_PROXY', None)
  if proxy is not None:
    setEnvar( 'http_proxy' , proxy  )
    setEnvar( 'https_proxy', proxy  )
    if noProxy is not None:
      setEnvar( 'no_proxy' , noProxy)

def jpath( dict1, path, sep = '.', default = None):
  # Traverse a hierarchy of dictionaries, as described by a path, and find a value. 
  ret = dict1
  if isinstance( path, str):
    particleList = path.split( sep)
  else:
    particleList = path
  for particle in particleList:
    if isinstance( ret, dict):
      ret = ret.get( particle, None)
    elif (isinstance( ret, list) or isinstance( ret, tuple)) and particle.isdigit():
      idx = int( particle)
      if (idx >= 0) and (idx < len(ret)):
        ret = ret[ idx]
      else:
        ret = None
    else:
      ret = None
    if ret is None:
      break
  if ret is None:
    ret = default
  return ret

def coerceToList( val):
  # Make it into a list.
  if val is None:
    return list()
  else:
    return val

def coerceToBoolean( val):
  if isinstance( val, str):
    return val.lower() == 'true'
  else:
    return bool( val)

def get_region():
  # Find the region for AWS services.
  return os.environ.get( 'REGION', os.environ.get( 'AWS_REGION', defaultRegion))

def get_assume_role_credentials( role_arn):
  # Switch to a role. We need sts:AssumeRole for this.
  global proxy
  if coerceToBoolean( os.environ.get( 'TURN_OFF_SSL', False)):
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts', verify=False)
  else:
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
  try:
    assume_role_response = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn=role_arn, RoleSessionName="configLambdaExecution")
    print( 'Switched role to ' + role_arn)
    return assume_role_response['Credentials']
  except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as ex:
    # Scrub error message for any internal account info leaks
    if 'AccessDenied' in ex.response['Error']['Code']:
      ex.response['Error']['Message'] = "AWS Config does not have permission to assume the IAM role."
    else:
      ex.response['Error']['Message'] = "InternalError"
      ex.response['Error']['Code'] = "InternalError"
    print(str(ex))
    raise ex

def get_client(service, event):
  # Get the AWS service client for the specified service.
  # If specified, switch roles and go through a custom service end-point.
  global proxy
  region = get_region()
  ruleRole = jpath( event, 'executionRoleArn')
  doAssumeRuleRole = coerceToBoolean( jpath( event, 'ruleParameters-parsed.Assume-Rule-Role', '.', False)) and (ruleRole is not None)
  parms = {}
  if coerceToBoolean( os.environ.get( 'TURN_OFF_SSL', False)):
    parms['verify'] = False
  if region is not None:
    parms['region_name'] = region
  if doAssumeRuleRole:
    credentials = get_assume_role_credentials( ruleRole)
    parms['aws_access_key_id'    ] = credentials['AccessKeyId'    ]
    parms['aws_secret_access_key'] = credentials['SecretAccessKey']
    parms['aws_session_token'    ] = credentials['SessionToken'   ]
  endPointEnvarName  = service.upper() + '_ENDPOINT'
  endPointEnvarValue = os.environ.get( endPointEnvarName, '')
  if endPointEnvarValue != '':
    parms['endpoint_url'] = endPointEnvarValue
  return boto3.client(service, **parms)

def get_configClient( event):
  # Get the AWS 'config' service, and store it in a global singleton.
  global configClient
  if configClient is None:
    configClient = get_client( 'config', event)
  return configClient

def initiate_Globals():
  # Mainly setup the proxy forward, if required.
  configClient = None
  setProxyEnvironment()

def evaluate_compliance( configuration_item, ruleParameters):
  # Evaluate the compliance of the given changed resource.
  # Return a dictionary in the standard 'evaluation' schema.
  referenceVpcSecurityGroupId = ruleParameters.get('vpcSecurityGroupId','')
  annotation = 'Ok'
  if ((jpath( configuration_item, 'configuration.engine') == 'oracle-ee') and
      (configuration_item.get('resourceType','') == 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance')):
    ok = False
    for vpcSecurityGroup in coerceToList( jpath( configuration_item, 'configuration.vpcSecurityGroups')):
      actualId = vpcSecurityGroup.get('vpcSecurityGroupId','')
      ok = ((actualId == referenceVpcSecurityGroupId) or
            (vpcSecurityGroup.get('status','inactive') != 'active'))
      if not ok:
        # The security group was active, but was not equal to the prescribed one.
        annotation = 'Wrong security group'
        break
    if ok:
      # All active security groups, and at least one, are the prescribed one.
      compliance_type = 'COMPLIANT'
    else:   
      if referenceVpcSecurityGroupId == '':
        annotation = 'Malformed rule parameter configuration'
      if annotation == 'Ok':    
        annotation = 'No security groups'
      compliance_type = 'NON_COMPLIANT'   
  else:
    # This rule only deals with oracle-ee RDS databases.
    compliance_type = 'NOT_APPLICABLE'       
  evaluation = dict()
  evaluation['ComplianceResourceType'] = configuration_item['resourceType']
  evaluation['ComplianceResourceId'  ] = configuration_item['resourceId']
  evaluation['OrderingTimestamp'     ] = configuration_item['configurationItemCaptureTime']
  evaluation['ComplianceType'        ] = compliance_type
  evaluation['Annotation'            ] = annotation
  return evaluation

def printEnvars( envarList):
  for envarName in envarList.split(','):
    envarValue = os.environ.get( envarName, None)
    if envarValue is not None:
      print( f'Envar {envarName} == {envarValue}')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  global configClient
  # Phase 1: Setup and parsing input.
  # Uncomment this when debugging:
  #   print( 'event == ' + json.dumps( event))
  printEnvars( 'PROXY,NO_PROXY,TURN_OFF_SSL,REGION,CONFIG_ENDPOINT')
  initiate_Globals()
  invokingEvent     = json.loads( event.get('invokingEvent','{}'))
  event['invokingEvent-parsed'] = invokingEvent
  ruleParameters    = json.loads( event.get('ruleParameters','{}'))
  event['ruleParameters-parsed'] = ruleParameters
  print( 'Config rule Arn == ' + event.get( 'configRuleArn', ''))
  print( 'Rule parameters == ' + json.dumps( ruleParameters))
  get_configClient( event)  
  configuration_item = invokingEvent['configurationItem']
  # Phase 2: Evaluation.
  evaluation = evaluate_compliance( configuration_item, ruleParameters)
  # Phase 3: Reporting.
  evaluations = list()
  evaluations.append( evaluation)
  mode = ruleParameters.get( 'Mode', 'Fully-Operational-DeathStar')
  if mode == 'Fully-Operational-DeathStar':
    response = configClient.put_evaluations( Evaluations=evaluations, ResultToken=event['resultToken'])
  elif mode == 'Put-Evaluations-Test':
    response = configClient.put_evaluations( Evaluations=evaluations, ResultToken=event['resultToken'], TestMode=True)
  else:
    response = {'mode': mode}
  # Uncomment this when debugging:
  #   print( 'response == ' + json.dumps( response)) 
  print( 'evaluations == ' + json.dumps( evaluations)) 
  return evaluations
```